# Woocommerce - How to get product cropped images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've searched and tried fixing this myself for several hours, however, I cannot find a proper solution.

How can I get the product cropped images?

I tried with **WC_Product::get_gallery_image_ids()** and **wp_get_attachment_image_src()** but the output is only the original image

I have set the sizes of the images in Woocommerce -> Products -> Display and chosen hard crop.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your reply, this is what I missed: **shop_thumbnail, shop_catalog, shop_single**.

```
   wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail');
   wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_catalog');
   wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_single');
```